# How move up UITextField with keyboard if using Navigation Controller Swift

Tags: swift, uitextfield

I try move up UITextField, but does not work if use Navigation Controller, and `print(self.view.frame.origin.y)` write `-216`

[image]

Everything works perfectly if you do not use Navigation Controller

```
class RegistratoinViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

@IBOutlet weak var nameTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var emailTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var passwordTextField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var confirmPasswordTextField: UITextField!

var activeTextField: UITextField!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    singUpButton.enabled = false
    self.hideKeyboardWhenTappedAround()

    self.nameTextField.delegate = self
    self.emailTextField.delegate = self
    self.passwordTextField.delegate = self
    self.confirmPasswordTextField.delegate = self

    self.nameTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark
    self.emailTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark
    self.passwordTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark
    self.confirmPasswordTextField.keyboardAppearance = UIKeyboardAppearance.Dark
    self.emailTextField.keyboardType = UIKeyboardType.EmailAddress
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(RegistratoinViewController.keyboardWillShow(_:)), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self.view.window)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: #selector(RegistratoinViewController.keyboardWillHide(_:)), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self.view.window)
}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!
    let keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
    self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height
}

override func viewWillDisappear(animated: Bool) {
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: self.view.window)
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().removeObserver(self, name: UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: self.view.window)
}

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {
    let userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject] = sender.userInfo!

    let keyboardSize: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size
    let offset: CGSize = userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey]!.CGRectValue.size

    if keyboardSize.height == offset.height {
        if self.view.frame.origin.y == 0 {
            UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
                self.view.frame.origin.y -= keyboardSize.height
            })
        }
    } else {
        UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
            self.view.frame.origin.y += keyboardSize.height - offset.height
        })
    }
    print(self.view.frame.origin.y)
}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

It will be a way easier if you use a scroll view and scroll it when the keyboard is displayed. Here you can check how to do so:

http://blog.apoorvmote.com/move-uitextfield-up-when-keyboard-appears/?lang=ca